# Is #defining within a block really a code smell?

Tags: c++, c, macros, preprocessor

I read that #defining and #undefining inside a block is a code smell. Why is that? Also, I see that in the code(just a sample that shows what I have in the actual code), this compiles,

```
if(x == 1000) {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
} else {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
}
```

But this does not compile,

```
if(x == 1000) {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
} else {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 2
}
```

with the error `warning C4005: 'MACRO_EXAMPLE' : macro redefinition`

How does this get preprocessed? How does it work?

Comment: You can use the `if` and `ifdef` directives to define a specific macro at compile time, it's not inherently bad practice.

Comment: It's not code smell, it just doesn't work.

Comment: preprocessor directives pay no attention to anything except lines starting '#'.

Comment: Some may disagree, but I'd actually argue against them in most situations. Macros have their usefulness but global defines can get out of hand pretty quickly, especially with `constexpr` is slowly being added to things.

Comment: You simply should avoid macros at all. There are rare circumstances where we still need macros, but never for constant definitions. And propagate constants ( compile time ) with dependency of run time states did never work! This is not dependent on macro or constexpr or others. So you should decide to need compile time constexpr or runtime values. What your code shows is misunderstanding of the preprocessor & compile & run time behavior. So please start reading about the mentioned times ...

Comment: @pm100 this is not quite true, it must process comments

Comment: Pre-processor directives such as this are used all the time in embedded software development. I think context is important to this question. What kinds of platforms are we talking about? What kinds of code: low-level drivers, or higher-level interface stuff? Even within that, use of macros is dependent on the situation and use case.

Answer (score 11):

preprocessing happens before your code is analyzed.  This means that the if/else is ignored and

```
if(x == 1000) {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
} else {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
}
```

is actualy treated as

```
#define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
#define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
```

which is okay because you use the same value.  On the other hand

```
if(x == 1000) {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
} else {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 2
}
```

becomes

```
#define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
#define MACRO_EXAMPLE 2
```

and since the value of the macro has changed it is an error

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor, which handles things like `#define`, operates conceptually before the rest of your program gets parsed.  Among other things, this means that preprocessor definitions do not honor block scope.  The compiler does not notice if you've done a `#define` inside of a `{` ... `}` block.  There's no mechanism to automatically do an `#undef` at the end of a `{` ... `}` block.

You can do this by hand, if you want: you can use a `#define` inside a block, and remember to do your own, explicit `#undef` at the end of the block.  But it's all on you: the compiler won't check your work, or warn you if you get it wrong.

And for this reason it's considered bad practice.  (I guess that's what you mean by "a code smell".)  It's bad practice because it's error-prone, and there's no good, automatic way to catch any errors.

If you use a preprocessor `#define` at all, it should be global (because, basically, it *is* global, whether you want it to be or not).

And, of course, global variables are frowned on, too.  And that's related to the fact that, these days, preprocessor `#define`'s are pretty much frowned on, all of them.

Like all questions of style, this one may be somewhat contentious.  When I say that hand-crafted block-scope preprocessor definitions are "bad style", that doesn't mean there's an ironclad rule against them.  If you want to, and you know what you're doing, you can get away with them; no one here can stop you.  (If you're writing code at work, and depending on your company's style guide, you may get scolded in a code review, though.)

As it happens, the code base I work with every day at my job is full of these "local scope" preprocessor definitions, because some of my predecessors thought they were nifty, I guess.  I don't like them, but they do work and they're not causing problems, so we haven't embarked on a campaign to eradicate them.

Answer (score 5):

Preprocessor directives pay no attention whatsoever to block scope, and they have their effects at compile time, no matter what.  Your code example

```
if(x == 1000) {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
} else {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 2
}
```

is 100% equivalent to writing

```
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 2
if(x == 1000) {
} else {
}
```

(except possibly for line numbers in debug info).  It should be more obvious now why that's an error.  This is also why defining inside a block is a code smell -- they have file-scope effects regardless.

(I vaguely remember a proposal to change this in C++ only, but I don't think it went anywhere.)

It *is* good style to define a macro that only one top-level construct has any business using right before that construct, and undefine it again immediately afterward.  You'll see this with [X-macros](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor_directives_and_macros#X-Macros), for instance:

```
#define X(a, b, c) b,
const int b_tbl[] = {
    #include "tbl.inc"
};
#undef X
```

But notice that the #define and the #undef are *outside* the definition of `b_tbl`, so they still read as file scope to a human.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are handled by a preprocessor, which runs before actual compilation. The preprocessor considers files as plain text, with preprocessor logic, different from source code logic.
use undef

```
#undef MACRO_EXAMPLE
```

This will undefine it so you can redefine later. It is **poorly styled but will work**.

```
if(x == 1000) {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
    //some code using the macro. Here it is expanded as 1
    #undef MACRO_EXAMPLE
} else {
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 2
    //some code using the macro. Here it is expanded as 2
    #undef MACRO_EXAMPLE
}
```

Comment: The preprocessor directives are  not controlled by the if-statement, sou you can't simply undefine the macro.

Comment: Really? They are line by line so within the code region the macro has the correct expansion. I have done it before.

Comment: this code doesnt do what the OP wants, but it certainly avoids the preproc redefinition error message

Comment: You can define/undefine wherever you want. So the code is valid! That the preprocessor did not take block scope into account is not the problem here! It is still bad practice, as macros are nearly unneeded anyway...  The macro can now be used inside the define area. Makes no sense but works ;)

Comment: @Klaus thanks I appreciate your support. I agree on the bad practice by the way.

Comment: @NeilButterworth You can absolutely undefine a macro, if you do it explicitly with `#undef`.  It's poor style, but it *will* work.

Comment: @Steve It will only work for the case in this answer which is _not_ the case the OP was asking about

Comment: All I added was a //comment.

Answer (score 0):

> How does this get preprocessed? How does it work?

The `if-else` lines don't affect the preprocessor.

As far as the preprocessor is concerned, those lines may as well as not exist.

The processor only cares about

```
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
```

in the first case and

```
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 1
    #define MACRO_EXAMPLE 2
```

in the second case.